# How do deferred statements, such as promise() and done(), work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help understanding the use of deferred methods like `promise()` and `done()`.

1st) In this example, `.promise()` is added to animate, in which `done()` is called after.

```
        var stack = new Array();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".droppable").each(function(){
                stack.push(new Droppable($(this)));  
            });
            dropNext();
        });

        function dropNext(){
            var droppable = stack.pop();
            if(droppable){                  
                droppable.drop().done(dropNext);
            }
        }

        function Droppable(domElem) {

            function drop() {
                return domElem.animate(
                    {
                        opacity : "1"
                    }
                ).promise(); 
            }
            this.drop = drop;
        }
```

What is the purpose of the promise? How does it work?

2nd) The jQuery docs give [this sort of example](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) with $.get, but don't know how it's different than using the anonymous function callback that's already provided with `$.get()`:

```
   $.get("test.php", {},
        function (result) { 
            alert(result);
        }
     );


    $.get( "test.php" ).done(
        function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    );
```

Isn't the anonymous function already a callback to return results to be parsed when they return from the server?

Comment: You should go through promise pattern to understand the reason

https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/

Comment: The purpose of 1st promise().done() is to wait for **all** animations/methods put in queue for matched element(s) to be successfully finished (resolved). `// Get a promise resolved when queues of a certain type
 // are emptied (fx is the type by default)`  jQuery put all animation by default in fx queue

Comment: Agree with @MayankGupta - you'd be much better google `javascript promise` and reading up on some `promise` documentation so you can understand what they are. Their usefulness is not limited to jQuery's `animate`

Comment: RE: 1st), the purpose of `.promise()` is commented right in your code: "*done() called when drop's promise() finishes*". Is there something in particular you do not understand about it?

Comment: @CrescentFresh I commented that because I can see that's what it is doing in this instance, but that doesn't mean I understand what it is for and what is going on

Comment: @Growler: ahh, I guess then your 1st question is rather "how does it work?" as opposed to what is its purpose.

Comment: @CrescentFresh yes indeed, edited above thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **promise** is a way of tracking a delayed result to make asynchronous operations *look like* synchronous operations. In the examples you gave with only one link in the chain, a callback works just as well. The real power is in multiple links and allowing errors to bubble up to the top level to be handled there.

For your first example, `animate` takes some time, so returning a `promise` that resolves when the animation is done allows you to make sure that the previous animation is finished before the next one begins. It says "*I'm telling you what to do **now**, but don't do it until this other thing is done.*" If your list `stack` here has 5 elements, you can loop through and chain them together with the code above. To do it with a callback, you'd have callbacks nested 5 levels deep.

The meat of the promise is `then`, allowing multiple operations to be chained together. Looking at the `$.get` example, imagine you want to do several API calls that depend on each other:

```
$.get("test.php", {},
    function (result) { 
        $.post("test-details.php", {data: result}, function(detail) {
            $.get("test-content.php", {id: detail.id}, function(content) {
                // do content stuff
                // whoa, this is getting deep
            });
        });
    }
 );
```

You can flatten this out using promises.

```
$.get( "test.php" ).then(function(result) {
    return $.post("test-details.php", {data: result});
}).then(function(detail) {
    return $.get("test-content.php", {id: detail.id});
}).then(function(content) {
   // do content stuff
});
```

You can than catch any errors that happen along the way by letting the go to the end of the chain.

For further reading, I recommend [You're missing the point of promises](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970) and [Promise Anit-https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) (from Bluebird.)

Comment: Excellent description despite my unclear question. Thanks for this. In your example with `then()`, I don't see `promise()`- is `then()` just a chaining version of `promise()`? Moreover, where is `done()` executed in this sequence?

Comment: `then` is the main method exposed by a promise. In jQuery, the result of an `ajax` (get/post) call is a `promise` so you don't need to call it explicitly. For the `animate` example, you could call `then` instead of `done`; `done` is the same as `then` except it tells you that the promise chain is actually finished.

Comment: To be clear, `promise()` is used to actually get the promise object so it can be returned. `then`, `done`, `catch`, etc are methods on the `promise` object that let you do things with the _value_ that is returned when the promise is `resolve`d.